# What data type to store interest rates and sums of compound interest calculations?

Tags: python, decimal, floating-accuracy, currency-formatting

I use `Decimal` for currency amounts. However, I was wondering what data type to put the interest rate in.

If I set it to `float`, I multiply the money amount (`Decimal`) with `float`, resulting in an 'inexact' `Decimal`. If I set it to `Decimal`, I get problems once there is compound interest, eventually also getting an inexact amount once the precision of the `Decimal` context is exceeded.

I tried to find information on how to save interest rates and saw some examples using `float` and assume that this is common practice.

Does that mean that I should go with `float` for interest and convert any amount to `Decimal` with a precision of '0.01' at the end of every financial year (and then use the returned value as starting value for the following year)? Would that be the correct way to code this?

Comment: what makes you think these are errors accumulating? `float` should not loose any precision in such calculation. can you give an example and show how you evaluate precision error?

Comment: @Evgeny You're right. It ends up being the same amount in the sample calculations I made and the error isn't big enough to show up. However, do you think the 'yearly' conversion to Decimal as described in the (updated) question is a good best practice? Or should Decimal conversions only take place when data is being 'stored'?

Comment: I think you also need to include rounding of floats to your set of operations, which is not the same as using Decimals. For stricter operations 'on the balance' you would rather use Decimals, which should add up stricter. For  calculating the coumpound rate you can perform the operation on floats and the round. I think there is important difference between rounding (dropping insignificant ammoints) and decimal representation (overcoming binary representation format).